# Find gateway address and netmask?

Tags: terminal, network

I come from the land of windows, where the `ipconfig` command shows four important pieces of information: IP address, netmask, gateway address, and MAC address.

However, on a Mac, `ifconfig` only shows IP address and MAC address.

Where can I find the gateway address (e.g. 192.168.1.1) and the netmask (e.g. 255.255.255.0)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `ifconfig` on OS X you can find netmask :

```
inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

netmask 0xffffff00 means 255.255.255.0

And for finding gateway address use `arp -a` or as [geekosaur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4177/geekosaur) said use `netstat -nr | grep '^default'`.

Answer (score 6):

On most Unix-like systems, including OSX, that information comes from `netstat -r` (`r` for "route").